# Intersection of Entities

Tags: c#, intersection, eyeshot

I want to create a while loop to **Translate** some entities which have **intersections** with each other. But the `Entity.Intersects()` method is protected. Is there any other solution to find intersections with Eyeshot methods?
My entities are `Region` in XY-Plane.
(I also tried `UtilityEx.DoOverlap(Mesh, Mesh)` by converting my regions to mesh, and it didn't work, since I can see the overlapping area of my entities in my Eyeshot Model.)

```
public static void MoveIntersectedEntity(List<Mesh> mainList, ref Mesh movingMesh, bool moveUp = false)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < mainList.Count; i++)
    {
      while (UtilityEx.DoOverlap(mainList[i],movingMesh))
        {
          if (moveUp)
            movingMesh.Translate(0,2,0);
          else
            movingMesh.Translate(0,-2,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found my answer. The `Region` class has a method of intersection that will return an array if there was an intersection between two regions.

```
Region[] result = Region.Intersection(region_1, region_2);

public static T[] Intersection<T>( 
   T a, 
   T b 
) 
   where T : Region, new()
```

If the `result.Length > 0` then we have an intersection.